# C++ socket not receiving incoming packets, works in Python

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

I haven't been able to find a similar question so here it goes.

I have a Linux box that is directly connected to another machine via a 10GbE cable. The machine on the other end is pushing 8kB UDP frames to a NIC on my Linux box. I am able to see the incoming UDP packets using iptraf and confirm that they are arriving at the expected NIC, ip address, and port number.

I am able to open a socket and read this data using Python with the following snippet:

```
import socket
ip = '192.168.4.5'
port = 60001
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((ip, port))
data = sock.recv(8192)
```

This gives me no issues other than Python is just too slow and I end up losing network packets no matter how tight I make my loops. The data is coming in over a 10GbE link and is running at full throttle.

So get over this latency issue I decided to turn to writing up a data recorder in C++/C.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <iostream>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sock;
ssize_t n;
socklen_t length;
in_port_t port;
const char *ip_addr;
socklen_t fromlen;
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr_in from;
char buf[8192];


ip_addr = "192.168.4.5"; // host to listen on
port = 60001; // port to listen on

std::cout << "ip address: " << ip_addr << std::endl;
std::cout << "port: " << port << std::endl;

// create inet socket
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (sock < 0) error("Opening socket");
else std::cout << "socket opened.\n";

length = sizeof(server);
memset(&server, 0, length); // initialize with zeros

server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_addr);
server.sin_port = port;

// bind to socket address and port
if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server, length)<0)
   error("binding");
else std::cout << "binding successful\n";

// check binding status
struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
socklen_t socket_addr_len;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {

    std::cout << "iter: " << i << std::endl;
    n = recv(sock, buf, 9000, 0);

    if (n<0) error("recv");
    std::cout << "received a datagram: ";
    for (int k=0; k<10; k++){
        std::cout << buf[k];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
return 0;
}
```

The C program above hangs forever on `recv()`. If I make it non-blocking then it returns `EAGAIN`, indicating that there is nothing to read. I tried using `getsockname` to determine if the socket was actually binding to the correct address; it is.

It seems odd to me that I'd have an issue with this when the Python version has no problems reading from the socket and I can visually confirm that there is data incoming. My guess is that there is an issue with my socket setup in C.

Another bit of information that may be relevant is that my Linux box has 1 other interface on the same subnet.

#### Interfaces on Linux box

- eth1: 192.168.4.1
- eth2: 192.168.4.5

#### Interface on remote machine

- eth0: 192.168.4.10

#### sample output from iptraf

`UDP (8220 bytes) from 192.168.4.10:10000 to 192.168.4.5:60001 on eth2`

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What about endianess of your port value?

Comment: Isn't there some "Port unreachable" message sent when you get that UDP packet?

Comment: Will I be wrong if I assume you should not use recv but either recvfrom or recvmsg instead since you're working with UDP?

Comment: @Gerhardh, I just edited to show that my eth2 is in fact ...4.5. Thanks for that!

Comment: @dmi: It depends on the usage of the data. If the program will only receive data and not send any response you can use recv().

Comment: @Gerhardh, that's what I mean. According to the manual: `The recv() call is normally used only on a connected socket (see connect(2)) and is identical to recvfrom() with a NULL src_addr argument.`, and I don't see any connection here.

Comment: @dmi, _normally_ a program will not only receive data but also send responses. If you only receive and log data it doesn't matter if you have a connection or not.

Comment: @dmi, possibly. I'm no expert here but my understanding is that if I'm not interested in the address of the sender of the packets then I can just set src_addr and addrlen to NULL in recvfrom()...at which point it is equivalent to just using recv() with flags set to 0.

Comment: also i should add that before implementing qianfg's fix I also tried using recvfrom without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

server.sin_port = **htons**(port);

Comment: this got the data flowing! thank you!. I wonder if this is related to @Gerhardh's comment about the endianness of the port.

Comment: Yes. That was meant to put you in the direction.